# How to set navigation bar to transparent in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar, ios11

How to set navigation bar to transparent and get smooth transition from normal to transparent in iOS 11?

before iOS 11, I find the `_UIBarBackground` view and set it's `alpha` in `viewWillAppear:`, and it worked fine when pop, push and swipe back.

But in iOS 11, `_UIBarBackground`'s alpha will be set to 1 after `viewDidAppear` automatically.

So I'm wonder, is there any other perfect solutions?

Comment: Did you try `uicolor.clearcolor`?

Answer (score 3):

- Set 'Under top bars for view controller' in storyboard, so your view will be under navigation bar
- Add subview to your view with frame {0,0,screenWidth,64}, or use auto layout constraints for it.
- Set background color of that view:

[image]

Set background of navbar to transparent:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                             forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Now you can change yelow view to transparent with animation

Example project: https://github.com/josshad/AnimatedNavBar

Comment: In this way, I must add this view in every view controller, that's not quiet an easy way I think.

Comment: Yeah. But in this case you use only public api. code for creating navbar transparent you may transfer to the category of uinavigationcontroller. Code of creating colored header view -- in uiviewcontroller subclass.

Comment: ```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                             forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```
just this 2 line

Comment: IMHO, The view background color beneath navigation bar is also very important since the navigationBar(_UIBarBackground) also tries blending that color below. If the view background color is pure white. Then the navigation bar may not seems transparent to the viewer